# MS Visual Studio 2005 - DOS window filling screen

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, dos

Whenever I save code while using Visual Studio 2005, an MS-DOS window fills the screen (very) briefly several times. I suspect it is something to do with IntelliSense. This has happened for several months now, and I don't know what initially caused it to start behaving the way it has. It is quite annoying, so I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem; and if so, what they did to resolve it?

Update: having pressed Alt+Enter while it was running, I got a glimpse of the program name: it's the VBC (Visual Basic Compiler). Any ideas on how to make this not fill the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since solved here: https://superuser.com/questions/239049/how-to-stop-command-line-program-from-running-in-full-screen-mode. Definitely worth knowing!